# Is it possible to remotely/wirelessly access a device via ssh and then use another wifi adapter to turn on monitor mode?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi and since it's a very portable little thing, I decided to try and tinker with the network using that instead of trying with my phone.

My question is, is it possible to and how do I connect 2 WiFi adapters to the Pi and then use the first to login via SSH from my phone; so the second could be set to monitor mode?

Comment: be sure to add a *route* naming the ssh client address via wifi 1 (dev vlan0?) targeted to the client or the router to reach the client

Comment: @Skaperen I'm sorry I didn't quite get you.. Could you explain a bit more?
and the wifi1 will actually be a hotspot from my phone so i guess its basically the router trying to connect to the pi via ssh, as far as my limited knowledge goes